# improving mysql performance

Tags: mysql, performance, codeigniter

Here is a screenshot of mysql explain command on a common query:
http://cl.ly/3r34251M320A1P2s3e1Y

I have 3 different tables I have to join together to extract the data I want. This is the main CI model code using activerecord

```
    $this->db->select('articles.id, articles.title, articles.link, articles.updated_time, articles.created_time, shows.network,shows.show_id, shows.name');
    $this->db->from('articles')->order_by('updated_time','desc')->offset($offset)->limit($limit);
    $this->db->join('labels', 'articles.remote_id = labels.articleid');
    $this->db->join('shows', 'shows.show_id = labels.showid');
```

Can anyone suggest any ways to improve the schema or query performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What makes your query slower is mysql use of temporary tables and filesort which means it can't efficiently use the index and creates a temporary table (many times on disk!).
It usually happen when you join a table using one index and sort it by another index or use a condition on another index. 
First thing you can do is read about this issue and see if you can, at least, avoid the use of temporary disk tables. 
[How mysql uses temp tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html)